# cURL not working with GET var and fopen - PHP

Tags: php, curl, get

I open `test1.php` in my browser, which should call `test2.php` with the GET variable `id` in the url which in turn should append the id and time to a local text file called `test1.txt`

But it doesn't work.

If I call `test2.php` directly with the GET var it works just fine - `http://www.example.com/test2.php?id=123456` - but it doesn't work when I load `test1.php` in my browser.

test1.php

```
curl_setopt_array(
$ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/test2.php?id=123456',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0
));

curl_exec($ch);
```

test2.php

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])) {
  die();
}

$ID = (int)$_GET['id'];

$myfile = fopen("test1.txt", "a") or die();
$txt = $ID . " - " .time() . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Is there a security measure in php to prevent this kind of action or am I just missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Do you see the `id=123456` parameter when you check the server access log?

Comment: You bring up the very bane of my life and that which has caused me to go down this route in the first place. My server access logs are being managed by Plesk and are a nightmare to access (other than through the Plesk control panel). So instead of grepping the access logs for the info I'm after I'm having to do it with php, hence this cURL setup writing the id and time to my own text (log) file. So in short - I have no idea as the apache logs are murder to navigate.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this wouldn't work. Scripts use `curl` with URL parameters all the time.

Comment: I just tried this on my server and it worked fine.

Comment: Check the URL in `test1.php` carefully for typos. Since you've obviously edited the code to post it here, the problem may be in something you changed.

Comment: For instance, when I'm testing, I frequently type `&` when I mean `?` in a URL.

Comment: Just checked and double checked, all present and correct. Is there any way I can echo the curl request on test1.php? I tried echo $ch; and it returns nothing.

Comment: `echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`

Comment: You never set `$ch`. You need `$ch = curl_init();`.

Comment: There we go.. I knew I was doing something wrong lol. Code blind... Thanks so much bro, that would have tormented me all evening ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `$ch`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
url_setopt_array(
    $ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/test2.php?id=123456',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0
));

curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are supposed to call test2.php, but in the code I see that you are calling the same file.

```
    curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/test2.php?id=123456',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 0
    ));
```

Should work.

Comment: Sorry I changed that, the actual code was correct, just in my environment I had the files the other way around, test1 was test 2 and test2 was test1, thought it would be clearer if I switched them for the question but forgot to change the curl url ref. What you see in the question now is correct and still not working.

Comment: Are both test1 and test2 in the same domain ?

Comment: Yep everything is in the same domain, same directory (webroot).

Comment: @Nandan Why would that matter? There's no cross-domain restriction on PHP, only AJAX from the browser.

Comment: No, I am just thinking, if both are in the same domain, he can change his approach. He doesn't have to make curl request. That's what I am thinking.

Comment: What you thinking?

Comment: And do either of you have any idea why this wouldn't be working? cURL is active and working on other areas of my site so I know it's not that. The txt file is writeable, so I know it's not that. The only thing I can think is that the cURL request isn't sending the GET var as it should be?

Comment: Instead of making the curl request to the second page, why don't you wrap it up as a function in the first page itself. ?

Comment: If it were all staying in php that would indeed be the easiest option, but it's not. test1.php is actually going to be embedded in AS3 in a flash movie, so the flash movie would execute test2.php. test1.php won't even exist, I was just testing curl to see that it worked as I expected before I tucked into actionscript.

Comment: AS3 runs on the client, not the server. How would `curl` be involved in that?

Comment: When you run the test2 page directly, what out put you see? Is that a flash file running or any specific output ?